# Folder List through JQuery Ajax Call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, treeview

I want to generate a list of folders on a page (through an AJAX call) and then on click of any of this folders a sub list to be generated.

The problem is that `.on('click'...` method doesn't work. It should atleast show *"User clicked on foo."* as console log, but looks like click handler is not getting called.

**JS**:

```
generateTreefn('/');

function generateTreefn(path){
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    url: '/bin/getFilepaths',
    data: {
      path: path
    },
    success: function(jsonArray) {
      var htmlValue="<ul>";
      jQuery.each(jsonArray, function(data,item) {
        htmlValue +="<li id="+item+">"+item+"</li>";
      });
      htmlValue=htmlValue+"</ul>";
      console.log(htmlValue);   
      $("#tree").replaceWith(htmlValue);
    }
  });
}


$('#treeview-container').on('click', function(event) {
  console.log('User clicked on foo.');
  // Need a logic to select the folder from generated list
  // so as i can call "generateTreefn" with selected value.

});

$('#treeview-container').on('dblclick', function(event) {
  var targetPath = $(this).attr("id");
  $("#targetPath").text(targetPath);
});
```

**HTML**:

```
<div id="targetPath"></div>
  <div id="treeview-container">
  <div id="tree"></div>
</div>
```

**/bin/getFilepaths** (returns JSON response as below) :

for parameter : `'/'` :

```
[
    "/ABC",
    "/DEF",
    "/GHI"
]
```

for parameter `'/ABC'` :

```
[
    "/OPQ",
    "/RST",
    "/WXY"
]
```

so on...

Comment: And the actual question is...? Please narrow the question, describing the exact problem, what does work and what doesn't.

Comment: Thanks for reply ! I just updated the question...on click method is not working. I also want to check if logic mentioned here is correct or not.

Comment: What does it mean: *"is not working"* ? What is happening or not happening? Please read this before posting a question: **[How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**

Comment: In above case it should atleast show "User clicked on foo." as console log, but looks like click handler is not getting called.

Comment: You have an error. You have delegated click event on a container, but forgot to pass a selector that trigger the event. instead of: `$('#treeview-container').on('click', function...` use `$('#treeview-container').on('click', 'selector', function...` . **[More info](http://api.jquery.com/on/)**

Comment: As for the *"Logic"*, you should post your attempts to solve the problem. We'll help you find the errors. Now it looks like you want us to write the whole code for you. Stack Overflow isn't a code writing service.

Answer (score 0):

The event object will have that information. Specifically, the target property.

alert(event.target.id);
Or
alert($(event.target).attr("id"));